# When can/can't you add "-less" at the end of a word?

Tags: suffixes, morphology, productive-affixes

When can or can't you add *-less* at the end of a word? What are the limitations to its productivity? Can you say anything at all, like *streakless* or *phoneless*? I am really sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here, the tags seemed all right to me.

Comment: The tags are fine! I don't know what this guy's problem is.

Comment: Original tag summaries: [[grammar]] "This tag is for questions about **morphology** and syntax"; [[descriptive-grammar]] "Descriptive grammar is a set of rules about language based on how it is actually used"; [[rules]] "Questions about the rules of English. This tag is overly broad and discouraged."  The tags are definitely appropriate, not "random", they are _absolutely_  "to do with" the question. The new tags are obviously more specific, but come on there's no point slating a newcomer for a sincere and GOOD first question.

Answer (score 5):

The morpheme -less seems to be only attachable to most nouns.

Try it with adjectives and it doesn't work: happyless is one and it sounds very wrong.

Comment: But isn't it simply because we have a better word for it? Like sad for example. What about adjectives that don't have a good enough antonyms?

Comment: Well, technically, that would be joyless. The *absence* of `X` is not the *opposite* of `X`. And it makes sense that you would generally have to have less of *something* (a noun). Having less of an adjective, verb or adverb (for example) would be quite difficult.

Comment: Well for most adjectives there's a good antonym. Of course some nouns don't work with that morpheme. Consider the noun "money" for example. You can say "moneyless" but it sounds a little strange. Also the same with milk—"milkless". So it seems that the morpheme works for collective nouns that can't be pluralized. Unless anyone could think of one.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez I would say that you could have [moneyless](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/sep/15/living-without-money-what-i-learned) or [milkless](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/3499632.stm) :) — I think it's more usual to see uncommon suffixes with a hyphen before them though: I'd expect to see penniless as one word, but wouldn't be surprised if *money-less* was written with a hyphen.

Comment: You're probably right, anotherdave. I never considered the use of a hyphen for less common used collective nouns.

Comment: I've been a member to this site for a few months now and still get surprised by the antagonizing and overly-critical members like RegDwight. It's so strange and annoying.

Comment: @RegDwigнt where is the weasel-wording in this answer? It reads very clearly to me. What is the twisted logic here? Both Wiktionary and the OED back up this answer, saying exactly the same thing that this answer does: that -less usually suffixes nouns, rarely adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

***-less*** can be added to nouns and more rarely to some verbs to form adjectives. It is never added to an adjective to form another part of speech.

When it means:

> without; lacking ([Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/less#:%7E:text=%2Dless,performed%20(resistless%3B%20tireless).))

it is logical that a preposition combines with a noun, not with an adjective:

> ***odourless*** = without odour
> ***penniless*** = without a penny

*Happiless  or *tidiless don't make sense grammatically. Instead, the prefix *un-* can be used to negate a quality or feeling expressed by an adjective (*unhappy, untidy*).

When *-less* means (more rarely)

> not able to (do something) or not able to be (done, performed, etc) ([Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/less#:%7E:text=%2Dless,performed%20(resistless%3B%20tireless).))

it is attached to a verb: *countless, resistless, tireless*.

Certainly, English is very flexible and you can create new ways of creating new words, but bear in mind that this is not a random, chaotic process. It takes skill and the right context to create words successfully.

Comment: "*Happiless or *kindless don't make sense grammatically." Could you substantiate this point, or is it merely a personal opinion? While " happiless" is a very rare word, "almost all the trusted dictionaries list "kindless" as a valid word. You might want to check The AHD, MW, and so forth, for instance.

Comment: Agreed, I chose bad examples. Will edit.